# Cómo saber el nombre de la clase que ha invocado a un método

Tags: php

Estoy construyendo un framework a modo de práctica.

Y estoy intentando saber cuál es la clase que ha invocado al método actual.

Ej.

```
Class A{
   public function escribir(){}
}

class B{

    $a = new A();
    a.escribir();
}
```

Todas las clases del framework tendrán acceso a $a.

Me gustaría sabe, qué clases están llamando al método escribir() de $a, sin tener que pasar como parámetro una referencia al objeto que hace la llamada.

Espero haberme explicado más o menos claro.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y trata de proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Puedes usar [`get_class()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-class.php). Intenta tu código leyendo la documentación, estudianto los ejemplos... y si tienes problemas pulsa en [edit] explicando el problema, agregando el código y los eventuales errores que tengas.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

He probado get_class() dentro del método escribir, pero me devuelve la clase a la que pertenece el método escribir. Y querría identificar qué clase está usando el método escribir().

Comment: @PedroCerrato edita por favor y agrega lo que hayas intentado con la recomendación de A.Cedano, además agrega todos los detalles que consideres relevantes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir con la pila de rastreo:

```
Class A{
   public function escribir(){
      $pila = debug_backtrace( DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 2 );
      $x = array_pop( $pila );
      echo $x['class'].':'.$x['function']; // Imprime B:__construct
   }
}

Class B{
   function __construct(){
      $a = new A();
      $a->escribir();
   }
}

new B();
```

Comment: Con herencia sí sabía hacerlo. 
La idea es saber si se puede hacer sin herencia. Entre dos objetos de clases que no tienen nada que ver. Y así saber quién está usando el método escribir.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Pedro: Sin herencia cambia el asunto, respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Exactoooo, justo eso es lo que andaba buscando.

Muchiiiiisimas gracias.

No sólo he aprendido a hacerlo, sino que con los comentarios anteriores también me ha dado ideas, con lo que he podido cambiar cosas en el framework de prueba que estoy haciendo.

De nuevo muchas gracias